# MongoDB google-diff-match-patch alternative

Tags: git, mongodb

Sorry for the question title - i don't know how to name it better :)

So, say, each user of a webapp has own quite a big node in MongoDB collection, which contains user's data. Each time when user modifies anything in there, some kind of git-like script saves diff, so user will be able to rollback this "mongoDB node".

I know how to implement it with `google-diff-match-patch` library, for example, but this requires a lot of additional code to be written. Is there more like ready-to-use solution (library or whatever)?

Comment: When you say "a node", do you mean a database, a collection, or a single document?

Comment: @VinceBowdren, "collection" will do